# XCode / OS X: Storyboard Minimum Requirements

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, storyboard

For the sake of some backward compatibility:

> What is the minimum required version of OS X that will run an
>   Application containing or utilizing Storyboards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storyboards introduced in **OSX Yosemite** are **not backwards compatible.**

Using storyboards, your app can only support **OSX Yosemite and later**.

For the sake of confirmation you can see that

In [NSViewController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSViewController/storyboard) the **storyboard** property's **Availability** is

> Available in OS X v10.10 and later.

Answer (score -1):

Storyboard Support is for Mac OS X 10.6.0 or greater (X86 only).
you can find detail here on [this wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#4.x_series) for xCode.

Comment: The OP is talking about OS X storyboards, not iOS storyboards. Your link covers storyboards on iOS, not OS X. Nofel's answer is correct. Mac storyboards will work on OS X 10.10 and later, not 10.6.